# Верстка макетов

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Вопрос по верстке макетов. Часто , скорее всего из за неопытности, при верстке по макетам приходится подбирать маргины, паддинги, различные размеры на глаз или же бороться с неточностью в этих величинах. Я не хочу сказать что не пользуюсь линейкой в фотошопе, но почему то на деле(у меня) к примеру отступ в 90px на странице будет совсем иначе отображаться чем отступ в 90px  в фотошопе. Вопрос в следующем: нормальна ли практика подгонять элементы в css на глаз и не иметь точности пиксель в пиксель на сайте как и в макете,ругаются ли заказчики, отсутствует ли этот недостаток у профессионалов?

Comment: В подгонке по макету нет ничего сложного, для этого существуют спец. плагины, например Perfect Pixel http://www.welldonecode.com/perfectpixel/  Он накладывает макет на верстку и сразу видно, где косяк.  Лично я работаю по следующей схеме, сначала задаю на глаз, а потом уже правлю по месту.

Comment: Если дизайн адаптивный, то точные размеры вообще сложно соблюдать. Обычно здесь задаются пропорции и «ограничители» размеров, скажем чтобы блок не развалился более какой-то ширины и не стал меньше такой-то (особенно актуально для рекламы).